# Single validation error for 4 validation issues

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using the following DTO for a Api endpoint POST;

```
 public record CreateNote : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Title cannot exceed 100 characters. ")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(4000, ErrorMessage = "Note cannot exceed 4000 characters. ")]
        public string Note { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string OwnerId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EnumDataType(typeof(NoteCategory))]
        public NoteCategory? Category { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var result = Enum.TryParse(typeof(NoteCategory), Category?.ToString(), out _);

            if (!result)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult(
                    $"Invalid Category.", new[] { nameof(CNoteCategory) });
            }
        }
    }
```

During testing, I noted that if I send the following request;

```
{
  "title": "",
  "note": "",
  "ownerId": "",
  "category": ""
}
```

I get the following 'single' validation error;

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-8e2b5f5ad19018a8ae000f23491f1327-4108b2b200781363-00",
    "errors": {
        "$.category": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[Core.DTOs.Notes.NoteCategory]. Path: $.category | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 16."
        ]
    }
}
```

Whereas, if I send the following;

```
{
  "title": "",
  "note": "",
  "ownerId": "",
  "category": "1"
}
```

I get 3 validation failures;

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-f4fffa35c7261c4040e972e9bf66e728-b6993dbe452745fa-00",
    "errors": {
        "Note": [
            "The Note field is required."
        ],
        "Title": [
            "The Title field is required."
        ],
        "OwnerId": [
            "The OwnerId field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

While I understand what the first example is telling me, ideally I want it to give me all of the validation errors and not just the error related to the enum.

If I change the underlying type for the Category field from an enum to a string, it gives me all 4 validation failures as desired, but at the cost of it not being an enum. Changing the data type also changes the Swagger schema and it no longer describes the expected values.

Is there a way to keep the enum and get all 4 errors in this scenario?

Comment: The first error happens when the object is being deserialized, so before the object is constructed and validated. It is a serialization error and not a validation error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to configure System.Text.Json off the top of my head to handle this, but I tried using Newtonsoft.Json instead and it worked with your code right away.

1. Add the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
2. In your Startup.cs or Program.cs (if using .NET 6), where you have `services.AddControllers();` or `builder.Services.AddControllers();`, change it to `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`

I passed in

```
{
  "title": "",
  "note": "",
  "ownerId": "",
  "category": ""
}
```

and received

```
{
    "errors": {
        "Note": [
            "The Note field is required."
        ],
        "Title": [
            "The Title field is required."
        ],
        "OwnerId": [
            "The OwnerId field is required."
        ],
        "Category": [
            "The Category field is required."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-3b5c4b2bc599cc6aedc93dca07cdeb4e-33a3ace0fe3a4efc-00"
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting observation. We have a standard not to use Newtonsoft right now, so if that's the only way to solve the issue, I guess there is a decision to be made. Thanks

Comment: Standards are standards and not rigid rules for a reason. System.Text.Json is getting better, but it hasn't had years of use and bug fixes. It'll take time to reach feature parity or get everything documented in an easy way with System.Text.Json to make completely switching away from Newtonsoft.Json viable.